# "fancy" vs "appeal"

Tags: difference

Context:

> People become quite illogical when they try to decide what can be eaten and what cannot be eaten. If you lived in the Mediterranean, for instance, you would consider octopus a great delicacy.You would not be able to understand why some people find it repulsive. On the other hand, your stomach would turn at the idea of frying potatoes in animal fat----the normally accepted practice in many northern countries. The sad truth is that most of us have been brought up to eat certain foods and we stick to them all our lives.

> No creature has received more praise and abuse than the common garden snail. Cooked in wine, snails are a great luxury in various parts of the world. There are countless people who, ever since their early years, have learned to associate snails with food. My friend, Robert, lives in a country where snails are despised. As his flat is in a large town, he has no garden of his own. For years he has been asking me to collect snails from my garden and take them to him. The idea never **appealed** to me very much, but one day, after a heavy shower, I happened to be walking in my garden when I noticed a huge number of snails taking a stroll on some of my prize plants. Acting on a sudden impulse, I collected several dozen, put them in a paper bag, and took them to Robert. Robert was delighted to see me and equally pleased with my little gift. I left the bag in the hall and Robert and I went into the living room where we talked for a couple of hours. I had forgotten all about the snails when Robert suddenly said that I must stay to dinner. Snails would, of course, be the main dish. I did not **fancy** the idea and I reluctantly followed Robert out of the room. To our dismay, we saw that there were snails everywhere: they had escaped from the paper bag and had taken complete possession of the hall! I have never been able to look at a snail since then

After the context, there is a quiz:

The idea of eating octopus has never ___ to me very much.

- a) fancied
- b) liked
- c) appealed

I see that the right answer is **a)**. But I chose **c)**. I think it should be that: Something appeals somebody, or somebody fancy something.

I don't know why **a)** is the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: "fancy to something"? Never heard that.

Comment: You don't need to quote so much text. Your question could be _Should I say 'The idea of eating octopus has never (a) fancied (b) liked, or (c) appealed to me very much?' I thought the answer was (c) but I am told it is (a). Why?_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I chose **c)** for I learned it from the context.

Comment: The right answer is (c) and only that. Who told you otherwise?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for your reply. I find the answer (**a)**) in the answer sheet.

Comment: The answer sheet is wrong, if you have copied the question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is '*appealed*'.

- When you 'fancy' something, it is an indication of your preference *towards* something.
- When something 'appeals' to you, it displays qualities that attract you.

The difference is *direction*. Something cannot "fancy" *towards* you, but it can *appeal* to you.

"Fancied" could only be used in the direction of the object of desire, ie "I fancied the idea".